# select2 remote displaying label instead of id when selecting a value from results

Tags: jquery-select2

I have the following code in an attempt when selecting a suggestion to display the selected value instead of the id. BUT I still need to pass the id as a value. This works fine when using select2 without remote on a regular select box, but it doesn't seem to work like this on a remote data source using an input.

Here is my results:

Search suggestions (working):
[image: Working as expected]

Selection Result (Not working as expected..I expect the search suggestion to be selected):
[image: Not working as expected]

Here is the code:

```
$("#specific_input_data").select2(
{
    minimumInputLength: 2,
    placeholder: <?php echo json_encode(lang('common_search')); ?>,
    id: function(suggestion){ return suggestion.value; },
    ajax: {
        url: <?php echo json_encode($search_suggestion_url); ?>,
        dataType: 'json',
       data: function(term, page) 
        {
          return {
              'term': term
          };
        },
        results: function(data, page) {
            return {results: data};
        }
    },
    formatSelection: function(suggestion) {
        return suggestion.value;
    },
    formatResult: function(suggestion) {
        return suggestion.label;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured i out. formatSelection needs to be `selection.label`